# Map Partial Json Data to Model Class

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a API Json data that contains a lot of information, but I only need to map one attribute to my model class, say Programname, I don't care of other information. I am using Json converter to DeserializeObject the API data. Is it possible to only map partial Json data to my model class? Right now, I receive error message as below if I only map one attribute of the Json data. Thanks.

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication2.Program]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication2.Models.Program]'.
```

```
 public class Program
    {
        public int Prog_id { get; set; }
        public string Programname  { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
           
            var Client = new HttpClient();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("appllication/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage res = await Client.GetAsync("my url");
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                 var result = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                List<Program> programs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Program>>(result);
              
                return View(programs);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(res.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            
        }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Program>
<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>
              Program
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Programname)
            </td>
         
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

change view model to list and fix a namespace

```
@model List<WebApplication2.Program>
```

and IMHO use await instead of .Result

```
var result = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
List<Program> programs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Program>>(result);
 return View(programs);
```

Comment: Cannot compile. Index.cshtml(22,52,22,63): error CS1061: 'Program' does not contain a definition for 'Programname' and no accessible extension method 'Programname' accepting a first argument of type 'Program' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>Done building project "WebApplication2.csproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: @user788448 You have to check your namespaces. I can not do this for you. I don't know in what name space you Programname class. It seems like you have declare the same class in too different places

Comment: hmm,  the Program.cs is under Models folder, the HomeController is under Controller folder, Index.cshtml is under the Views/Home folder. They are all under the WebApplication2, same namespace.

Comment: Could it be WebApplication2.Models for example? It is not WebApplicaton2 at all

Comment: I doubt it is because I didn't map the whole Json data to the model Program.cs. I tested a simple API example with full Json data mapping to model class and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out what the problem was now. The word "Program" is a reserved word in asp.net core. After I changed the Program to something else, it works. :/